# Asymmetric solution of heat equation with heat source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

As I guess, the solution $u(x,t)$ of heat equation on $S^n$ 
$$
\partial_tu=\Delta_g u
$$
must have some symmetry, I mean that ,  $\exists T_0>0$ st $\forall t>T_0$  $u(x,t)=u(-x,t)$, no matter  any smooth initial conditions. But I don't know whether the heat source could break this symmetry. For example, for some positive contant $p$, consider
$$
\partial_tu=\Delta_g u+u^p
$$
it is obvious that for enough small $p$, the solution have the above symmetry. So, what is the maximal $p$ such that the solution has above symmetry ?

Comment: Do you mean any smooth initial condition that also satisfy the symmetry?

Comment: @themaker  No, the initial condition is not symmetric. Besides, initial condition independ to time , I think  it is unmeaning to say initial condition satisfy my above symmetric.  In fact, I think  a situation is blow up before symmetic.

Comment: Why would it be unmeaningful? if $u_0(x)$ is the initial condition, then your symmetry condition would be $u_0(x) = u_0(-x)$ which looks pretty meaningful to me, even if doesn't depend on time. Besides, even for the linear heat equation, if the initial condition is not symmetric, you dont expect the solutions to be symmetric, even for big times.

Comment: for instance take $e_k(x)$ an eigen function of $\Delta_g$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ such that $e_k$ does not satisfy $e_k(x) = e_k(-x)$ (must be at least $1$ otherwise every function in $L^2(\mathbb S^n)$ would have this symmetry). Then $u(t,x) = e^{-\lambda_k t} e_k(x)$  is a solution of the heat equation that does not have the symmetry.

Comment: @themaker  Clever example. But the heat equation describe the heat diffusion, It should be symmetric after long time.  Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Well, your intuition is right but is not exactly what you wrote. For the linear heat equation, for big times, the solution will be **approximately** symmetric, even more, it will be approximately constant. More precisely: $\exists c, C, \gamma$ such that $\|u(t, x) - c\|_{L^2} \leq C e^{-\gamma t}$.

Comment: @themaker   Thanks very much.